# Manipulating a list to insert new elements

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list:

```
b = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {5, 5}, {6, 6}, {8, 8}, {10, 10}};
```

I want to insert new elements into the list:

```
ClearAll[n];
n = 1;
While[n < 10,
 If[Unequal[n, b[[n, 1]]], Insert[b, n, b[[n, 1]]]]
  n++
 ]
```

I expect to get this:

```
b = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 1},{5, 5}, {6, 6}, {7, 1}, {8, 8}, {9, 1}, {10, 10}};
```

However I get these errors:

```
Part::partw: "Part 8 of {{1,1},{2,2},{3,3},{5,5},{6,6},{8,8},{10,10}} does not \
exist"
Part::partw: "Part 9 of {{1,1},{2,2},{3,3},{5,5},{6,6},{8,8},{10,10}} does not \
exist"
```

Comment: Sorry, can't reproduce this. Quit your kernel and try again. You probably have some definition lingering around. BTW, I suppose you wanted a `;` before the `n++`.

Comment: insert doesnt change b, but returns the result, you need to do `b=Insert[..] `  (there are other issues, but thats the immediate one..)

Comment: George is right. Most of Mathematica's functions do not affect their arguments. There are some exceptions (like AppendTo and Increment), but in most cases Mathematica just returns a result that you then use to update the variable concerned. The description of `Insert` is terribly confusing/incorrect (*`Insert[list,elem,n]` inserts elem at position n in list.*)

Comment: Errors occur because `n` in `b[[n, 1]]` means the number of a sublist in a nested list, and `b` has only 7 sublists, so _Mathematica_ can't find next sublists when You force it to find 10 of them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For this problem you could first calculate the list of missing elements:

```
missing = Complement[Range@10, b[[All, 1]]];
(*  {4, 7, 9}  *)
```

Then `Fold` the insertions into the list:

```
Fold[Insert[#1, {#2, 1}, #2] &, b, missing]
(*  {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 1}, {5, 5}, {6, 6}, {7, 1}, {8, 8}, {9, 1}, {10, 10}}  *)
```

Comment: Or `Sort@Join[b, Thread[{missing, 1}]]`

Answer (score 5):

yet another idea, rule based:

```
Table[{i, 1}, {i, Max[b[[All, 1]]]}] /. (Rule[{#[[1]], 1}, ##] & /@ b)
```

note that I create a table of all elements `{i,1}` first and then replace according to `b`, based on the first entry of an element in `b`.

Depending on the list, maybe not the fastest idea...

Comment: This can simplified to `Table[{i, 1}, {i, First @ Last @ b}] /. (Rule[{#[[1]], 1}, #] & /@ b)`, and its probably a little faster too.

Comment: @m_goldberg: thanks - I guess I'll keep it, as I think the difference will be rather small and as nobody mentioned that `b` is sorted. But thanks for the input!

Answer (score 4):

Modification to Simons method:

after getting the missing elements

```
missing = Complement[Range@10, b[[All, 1]]];
```

use `Thread` and `Join`

`Sort@Join[b, Thread[{missing, 1}]]`

```
(*  {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 1}, {5, 5}, {6, 6}, {7, 1}, {8, 8}, {9, 
  1}, {10, 10}}  *)
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what the range of possible inputs are, but for this case, here is one way:

```
b = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {5, 5}, {6, 6}, {8, 8}, {10, 10}};

Module[{n = 0},
 b = Nest[If[++n; Unequal[n, #[[n, 1]]], Insert[#, {n, 1}, n], #] &, b, b[[-1, -1]]]
 ]

(* {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 1}, {5, 5}, {6, 6}, {7, 1}, {8, 8}, {9, 1}, {10, 10}} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

### [TimeSeriesResample](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeSeriesResample.html#)

```
TimeSeriesResample[b, 1, ResamplingMethod -> {"Constant", 1}]
```

> {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 1}, {5, 5}, {6, 6}, {7, 1}, {8, 8}, {9, 1}, {10, 10}}

Answer (score 1):

Just [`ReplaceRepeated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReplaceRepeated.html), [`Condition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Condition.html) and some patterns:

```
b //. {
  pre___,
  l : {i_, _}, r : {j_, _},
  post___
  } /; j != i + 1 :> {pre, l, {i + 1, 1}, r, post}
(* {1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 1}, {5, 5}, {6, 6}, {7, 1}, {8, 8}, {9, 1}, {10, 10} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SortBy[Union[b, {#, 1} & /@ Complement[Range[10], First[#] & /@ b]], First]
```

> {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 1}, {5, 5}, {6, 6}, {7, 1}, {8, 8}, {9, 
>     1}, {10, 10}}

Answer (score 1):

Using the automatic replacement feature of `Asssociation`:

```
 KeyValueMap[List] @ <|Thread[Range[10] -> Table[1, 10]], Rule @@@ b|>
```

{{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 1}, {5, 5}, {6, 6}, {7, 1}, {8, 8}, {9,
1}, {10, 10}}

Answer (score 1):

Another method using `GroupBy`:

```
f[b_] := Values[GroupBy[Sort@(Join @@ {b, Outer[PadRight[#, Last@Dimensions[b], 1] &@*List, 
         Complement[Range[Last@*Last@b], b[[All, 1]]]]}), First, #[[1]] &]]
f[b]

(*{{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 1}, {5, 5}, {6, 6}, {7, 1}, {8, 8}, {9, 1}, {10, 10}}*)
```

An alternative method using `SequenceCases` and [ConsecutiveQ](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/140472/ordered-subsequences-of-consecutive-integers):

```
ConsecutiveQ = Most[#] == Rest[#] - 1 &;(*By @Kuba*)
f[b_] := Catenate@Riffle[SequenceCases[b[[All, 1]], 
x : {_, ___}?ConsecutiveQ :> Transpose@ConstantArray[x, 2]], 
Most@Map[{{Last@# + 1, +1}} &, SequenceCases[b[[All, 1]], {_, ___}?ConsecutiveQ]]]
f[b]

(*{{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 1}, {5, 5}, {6, 6}, {7, 1}, {8, 8}, {9, 1}, {10, 10}}*)
```

Or using `SequenceCases` without using `ConsecutiveQ`:

```
f[b_?MatrixQ] := Catenate[Riffle[SequenceCases[#, 
a_ /; Times @@ Union[Differences[a]] <= 1 :> 
Transpose@Array[a &, 2]], List /@ (PadRight[#, 2, 1] & /@ 
Complement[Outer[List, Range[Last@#]], Transpose@{#}])]] &@b[[All, 1]]
f[b]

(*{{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 1}, {5, 5}, {6, 6}, {7, 1}, {8, 8}, {9, 1}, {10, 10}}*)
```